# Is it possible to know whether a property belonging to a class or its parent class

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual DateTime DateCreated
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
}

public class Child:Parent
{
......
}

  Type type = typeof(Child);

 //PropertyInfo DateTime = type.GetProperty("DateCreated");
```

Is there a way to know the property "DateCreated" is a parent property rather than a child property.

Comment: Yes, but can you explain why you need to know? There may be better ways to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: Try `type.GetProperty("DateCreated", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)` and check for null.

Comment: no particular use case here, just randomly pop up this question in my head.

Comment: @KeithPayne you are right, will you copy ur comments as an answer then i can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the property info's [`DeclaringType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx) value and see if it matches the type `Child`. If it doesn't match, then you know it's declared on the parent.

```
Type type = typeof(Child);
PropertyInfo dateTimeProperty = type.GetProperty("DateCreated"); 

bool declaredByParentClass = dateTimeProperty.DeclaringType != typeof(Child);
```

Alternatively, you can use an [overload of `GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx) to retrieve properties *only* declared on type `Child`:

```
Type type = typeof(Child);
PropertyInfo dateTimeProperty = type.GetProperty("DateCreated", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);

bool declaredByParentClass = dateTimeProperty == null;
```

If you simply want to check if it's declared from the parent class you can use this second method. However, I suspect you'll want to do something with that property even if it is declared on the parent, if so, you'll want to use the first method to avoid retrieving the property twice with different binding flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection. When you have an instance of `Type` in your hand and you want to see the properties that were declared *only* on that type, you can use the binding flag `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`:

> `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` to search only the properties declared on the `Type`, not properties that were simply inherited.